# How To Read String that contains Spaces, in C language

Tags: c, string

What is the most accurate way to read strings from the keyboard in C, when the string contains spaces in between words? When I use scanf for that purpose then it doesn't read a string with spaces.The second option is to use gets but it is supposed to be harmful(I also want to know why?).Another thing is that I don't want to use any file handling concept like fgets.

Comment: How is the string input into the system? By the user? From a file? From TTY? Over a socket? This is too broad...

Comment: By user through keyboard

Comment: You probably want `fgets`.

Comment: Why don't you "want to use any file handling concept like fgets"? Do you know [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)?

Comment: Concerning `gets`: Read [this So article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: 1. If you don't want to use `fgets` you will have to reimplement it, poorly. 2. There is no keyboard in the C language.

Comment: It is never safe to use scanf and gets function to read a string. Please use fgets to read from the standard input(Keyboard).

Comment: @VimalBhaskar "It is never safe to use scanf" --- not true. "and gets" --- **there's no gets**. It is removed from the language precisely because it is never safe. The scanf family will remain a part of the language.

Comment: @n.m scanf has its own demerits. Please read the following reference documents and earlier stackoverlow issues ..http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: @VimalBhaskar scanf may be inconvenient or inappropriate for some tasks, but it's far from never being safe.

Comment: Buffer overflow maybe a serious issue for the above case. If you think buffer overflow is not a serious issue then i will rephrase my answer to "scanf() is inappropriate for some scenarios and gets() is unsafe". Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

These are 2 ways to read strings containing spaces that don't use `gets` or `fgets`

2. You can use `getline` (POSIX 2008 may not exist in your system) that conveniently manages allocation of the buffer with adequate size to capture the whole line.

   ```
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t bufsize = 0;
   size_t n_read; // number of characters read including delimiter
   while ((n_read = getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin)) > 1 && line != NULL) {
       // do something with line
   }
   ```
3. If you absolutely want `scanf`, in this example it reads to the end of line unless the line has more than the specified number of chars minus 1 for the delimiter. In the later case the line is truncated and you'll get the remaining chars in the next `scanf` invocation.

   ```
   char line[1024];
   while (scanf("%1023[^\n]\n", line) == 1) {
       // do something with line
   }
   ```

I should also point out that when you read strings from the keyboard with `scanf` for example, you are actually reading from a file with file pointer `stdin`. So you can't really avoid *"any file handling concept"*

Comment: The size in the format doesn't include the terminating null byte. The number in the format should be 1023.

Answer (score 2):

@user3623265,

Please find a sample program which Uses fgets to read string from standard input.

Please refer some sample C documents as to how fgets can be used to get strings from a keyboard and what is the purpose of stdin.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
char str[80];
int i;
printf("Enter a string: ");
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

i = strlen(str) - 1;
if (str[i] == '\n')
    str[i] = '\0';

printf("This is your string: %s", str);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if I *immediately* press `^D` on your prompt? (I am on a Linux-like system, so "you get a string containing `^D`" is not a valid answer.)

Comment: I have given him a basic example as to how to read from keyboard instead of using scanf() and gets function. Basically there are multiple ways to avoid the display of EOF(Ctrl+D). The question asked was regarding the effectiveness of using scanf() or gets or some other function. Hence out of these two my opinion/i preferred fgets() . If what I have expressed/explained is wrong then please do correct me as i am open to learn here. That is why i have joined this community.

Comment: I mentioned it because it will lead to an input string with a length of **0**, and `strlen(str)-1` will attempt to access memory it's not allowed to. You should always check the return result of `fgets`, which *specifically* checks for [end of input with no characters entered](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Comment: Check with this: `i = strlen(str); if ( i > 0) { if (str[i-1] == '\n'.........`. If that `if` statement is not true, then buffer overflow has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third option, you can read the raw data from `stdin` with the `read()` call:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[1024];
    ssize_t n_bytes_read;

    n_bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
    if (n_bytes_read < 0) {
        // error occured
    }
    buf[n_bytes_read] = '\0'; // terminte string

    printf("\'%s\'", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Please not that every input is copied raw to `buf` including the trailing return. That is, if you enter `Hello World` you will get

```
'Hello World
'
```

as output. Try [online](https://repl.it/FDo4/9).

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on not having a FILE * in scope, use getchar().

```
  char buff[1024];
  int ch;
  int i = 0;

  while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' )
    if(i < 1023)
      buff[i++] = ch;
  buff[i] = 0;

  /* now move string into a smaller buffer */
```

Generally however it's accepted that stdout and stdin and FILE * are available. Your requirement is a bit odd and, since you are obviously not an advanced C programmer who has an unusual need to suppress the FILE * symbol, I suspect your understanding of C IO is shaky.